# Oracle Merge Into's Using clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't work with Oracle regularly, occasionally I am charmed with opportunities though. Recently I was confronted with the situation below and am trying to make sense of this.

Attempting to follow documentation about the [Merge statement from Oracle's SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) I created the MERGE INTO statement below. It compiles but does not work correctly.  *When the ON (**tbl.field_name = S.field_name**) **evaluates to False** the logic **does not flow to the (WHEN NOT MATCHED)** section*

```
    MERGE INTO table_name tbl
         USING (SELECT field_name FROM table_name WHERE field_name = '12345') S
         ON (tbl.field_name = S.field_name)

         WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE . . . 
            -- flow arrives here when expected, this works correctly 

         WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT . . .
            -- When a match against (field_name) doesn't exist **flow never comes here?
```

The MERGE INTO statement below works correctly but I don't understand why it works correctly. A co-worker, who is now sequestered, helped me with this then left without explanation.  She only changed the USING and ON Clauses.  I am trying to understand how the *(**USING Dual**) part of this causes this to work correctly?*  **Or *why the USING Clause (in the example above with the explicit SELECT) does not work as expected?***  Can anyone help me with this?

```
    MERGE INTO table_name tbl
         USING dual
         ON (tbl.field_name = '12345')

         WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE . . . 
            -- flow arrives here when expected, this works correctly

         WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT . . .
            -- When a match against (field_name) doesn't exist **flow arrives here correctly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at the comparison between the source and target table the wrong way around.

The merge is based initially on the data that is in the source table, and *then* whether there is matching data in the target table. You seem to be expecting it to work the other way around.

With:

```
     USING (SELECT field_name FROM table_name WHERE field_name = '12345') S
     ON (tbl.field_name = S.field_name)
```

if there is a row in the source table with that value then `S` has a single row (assuming it's unique), and there may or may not be a matching row in the target table; it will go into either the matched or not-matched clauses as expected depending on what is in the target table but only using the values from the selected source row.

But if there is no row in the source table with that value then `S` is an empty result set, so there's nothing for the `ON` clause to do, so it's never really evaluated - and in that scenario it doesn't reach the not-matched clause. There is nothing to compare, and 'nothing' doesn't match *or* not-match anything else.

Whereas with:

```
     USING dual
     ON (tbl.field_name = '12345')
```

there is always exactly one row in `dual`, so the `ON` clause is always evaluated - though it doesn't actually use that `dual` row or its `dummy` column - and there may or may not be a matching record in the target table, so it goes into the expected branch. You can't have an empty result set from the source table as that is now `dual`, which can't be empty.

Either way it seems like your not-matched clause, at least, is not using data from `S`, which would normally be the case - otherwise the `dual` version would work either.

Comment: Thank you so helpful.  If I'm understanding correctly, when the Using clause returns (no rows) the ON Clause (and everything below it) is never evaluated? Essentially the Merge logic exits or stops executing when the Using clause returns (no rows).  Is this how you see this (in my first example's usage)?

Comment: Sort of. The `ON` clause and therefore the matched/not-matched clauses are only evaluated for the rows in the `USING` result set. In this case there are no rows, so they're never evaluated at all, yes. (There could be other scenarios where there are multiple rows in that result set, but it's still only those rows that are evaluated. It can never evaluate rows *which do not exist* in the source. Zero rows is just an extreme case, the logic is the same.)

Answer (score 2):

When '12345' is not found in `table_name.field_name`, in the first case you are **using** a table with no rows. Control DOES flow to the `when not matched then insert...` branch (not sure why you think it doesn't), but there is nothing to insert because `S` is empty. In the second example, even if that value is not found, you are **using** table `dual`, which does have one row. Regardless of what is in the parts of code you didn't share with us, you SHOULD absolutely expect different behavior from the two different MERGE statements.

Comment: I think that helps. Do I sound like I am on the right track with the following?  In my first case / top-most example, when there are no records where table_name.field_name = '12345', that (S) will have no rows and possibly that MERGE doesn't have a case for (no rows) and that neither (WHEN MATCHED) or (WHEN NOT MATCHED) will run? Does this sound correct?